# 100% height of div in bootstrap tabs

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I would like to make the green think on picture, but the red one is the default:

[image: vertical-boostrap-tabs]

So what I want to do is basically set some background on tab content area, and that area should be at least as height as tabs on the left, but if the content of green are will be longer, so the green area should be.

I am using just sample code from [bootstrap-vertical-tabs](https://github.com/dbtek/bootstrap-vertical-tabs)

and working example: http://dbtek.github.io/bootstrap-vertical-tabs/bare-demo.html

Thanks

Comment: If I understand correctly, you can give the tab content area a min-height equal to the hight of the tabs. If you add more content, the div will grow with it.

Comment: Yes, but problem is that the number of tabs is dynamic, so if I add some tabs then min-height will no longer correct...

Comment: Hmm, didn't know that. My last thought would be wrapping the entire thing in a div with height:auto, and then giving the tab content area a height of 100%;

Answer (score 2):

you can add class 'row' in bootstrap to your div content

Comment: Could you expand on your answer by showing an excerpt/snippet demonstrating what you mean, to make your solution clearer for the OP?

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if you still have this problem, but i solved it by changing the '100%' to '100vh' and this solve my problem.

Comment: `100vh` is actually full viewport height, not the height of the tabbed nav. And it's very buggy in IE9!